# Python: renaming a method while keeping backward compatibility

Tags: python, inheritance, rename

I had a base class `A` with a `old_name()` method. Subclasses used to inherit from `A` and override `old_name()` by first calling `A.old_name()`:

```
class A():                                                                 
    '''Old A class'''                                                      

    def old_name(self):                                                    
        print('foo')                                                       

class B(A):                                                                
    '''Old Subclass.'''                                                    

    def old_name(self):                                                    
        A.old_name(self)                                                   
        print('bar')                                                       

b = B()                                                                    
b.old_name()  # must print 'foo bar', prints 'foo bar'
```

Now, I want to change `old_name` into `new_name`. However, I don't want to break my API so I still want *old* subclasses like `B` to support both calls to `new_name()` and `old_name()`. I also want new subclasses (like `C`) to support both methods. By that, I mean that it must print `foo bar` whether `new_name()` was called or `old_name()` was called. I cannot modify class `B`: the only one I can change is class `A`.

Here is what I came up with. Unfortunately, `B` does not support a direct call to `new_name()` because it bypasses `b.old_name()`.

```
class A():                                                                 
    '''New A class. Now A has to support new_name AND old_name.'''         

    def old_name(self):                                                    
        self.new_name()                                                    

    def new_name(self):                                                    
        print('foo')                                                       

class B(A):                                                                
    '''Old Subclass, still using old_name'''                               

    def old_name(self):                                                    
        A.old_name(self)                                                   
        print('bar')                                                       

class C(A):                                                                
    '''New Subclass, now using new_name'''                                 

    def new_name(self):                                                    
        A.new_name(self)                                                      
        print('bar')                                                          


b = B()                                                                       
b.new_name()  # must print 'foo bar', only prints 'foo'. Bad.                       
b.old_name()  # must print 'foo bar', prints 'foo bar'. OK.                       

c = C()                                                                    
c.new_name()  # must print 'foo bar', prints 'foo bar'. OK.                     
c.old_name()  # must print 'foo bar', prints 'foo bar'. OK.
```

Any help would be greatly appriciated!

Comment: `B` will just have to implement `new_name`. Also you should use `warnings` to indicate that `old_name` is how deprecated.

Comment: I've edited the question to make clear that class `B` cannot be changed. I'll definitely use warnings when I've got this problem sorted, thanks.

Comment: Then you can't fix it unless you reverse the calls such that new_name points to old_name

Comment: Tried to do that: same issue with class `C` this time.

Answer (score 0):

You should like this

```
class A(object):                                                                 
    '''New A class. Now A has to support new_name AND old_name.'''         

    def old_name(self):                                                    
        self.new_name()                                                    

    def new_name(self):                                                    
        print('foo')                                                       


 class B(A):                                                                
    '''Old Subclass, still using old_name'''                               

    def old_name(self):                                                    
        # A.old_name(self)                                                   
        super(B, self).old_name()                                                   
        print('bar')                                                       


class C(A):                                                                
    '''New Subclass, now using new_name'''                                 

    def new_name(self):                                                    
        super(C, self).new_name()                                                      
        print('bar')                                                          


b = B()                                                                       

b.new_name()  # must print 'foo bar', only prints 'foo'. Bad.                       

b.old_name()  # must print 'foo bar', prints 'foo bar'. OK.                       

c = C()                                                                    

c.new_name()  # must print 'foo bar', prints 'foo bar'. OK.                     

c.old_name()  # must print 'foo bar', prints 'foo bar'. OK.
```

In order to print `foo bar` from `b.new_name()`, you need to overwrite your `new_name` and `old_name` in **Class B** like this

```
class B(A):                                                                
    '''Old Subclass, still using old_name'''                               

    def new_name(self):                                                    
        # A.new_name(self)                                                   
        super(B, self).new_name()                                                   
        print('bar') 

    def old_name(self):                                                    
        # A.old_name(self)                                                   
        super(B, self).old_name()                                                   
        # print('bar')
```

Comment: I've edited the question to make clear that class `B` cannot be changed.

Comment: why ```class B``` cannot be changed?

Comment: Because this is part of an API and many users have already implemented their own class `B`.